# run method onclick crash in android

Tags: java, android, xml, client-server

I am currently working on writing a simple message application on Android. I have the server in a class called `runServer`, which runs perfectly. Then i have a client in a method in my `mainActivity`. I have a `button`, which has an `onclick="startClient"`. but whenever i run an click on the `button`, i get an error.

```
03-11 13:01:40.622: E/AndroidRuntime(718): java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Could not find a method startClient(View) in the activity class com.example.datorkomprojekt.MainActivity 
for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'connect'
```

What can I do to solve this?

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Socket socket;
private ObjectInputStream ois;
private DataOutputStream dos;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message_id);
        String message = et.getText().toString();
        EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messages);
        et1.append(message);
        }
    });
}

    public void startClient() {
        socket = new Socket();
        InetSocketAddress ipPort = new InetSocketAddress("10.0.2.15", 4444);
        try {
            socket.connect(ipPort);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        Thread thread = new Thread();
        thread.start();
    }

}
```

server class

```
public class RunServer {

private ServerSocket server;
private Socket socket;
private DataInputStream dis;
private int port;

public RunServer(int port){
    this.port = port;
    Thread connectThread = new Thread( new Connect() );
    connectThread.start();
}

private class Connect implements Runnable {

public void run() {

    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
    System.out.println("Server running");
    while (true) {
        socket = server.accept();
            Thread clientThread = new Thread( new TalkToClient( socket ) );
            clientThread.start();
            System.out.println("someone connected");
    }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RunServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    try {
        server.close();
        } catch( Exception e ) {}
    }
}

private class TalkToClient implements Runnable{

    private Socket socket;
    public TalkToClient( Socket socket ) {
    this.socket = socket;
    }

public void run() {

    String clientMsg;
    try {
         dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        while ((clientMsg = dis.readUTF()) != null) {
            if (clientMsg.length() > 0) {

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new RunServer(4444);
}

}
```

XML layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bakgrund"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/ip"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ip_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/get_ip"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ip_id"
    android:text="@string/port"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/port_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/get_port"
    android:inputType="number" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/port_id"
    android:layout_below="@+id/port_id"
    android:text="@string/message"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/message_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/get_message" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/connect"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/message_id"
    android:text="@string/connect"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:onClick="startClient" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/send"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/connect"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/connect"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/connect"
    android:text="@string/send"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/status_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/connect"
    android:layout_below="@+id/send"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:text="@string/status"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/messages"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/status_id"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`public void startClient(View v)` .. this will be the signature of the method

**UPDATE:**

as everybody is posting the same answer I think I better improve my answer a bit. Although the single line has solved your problem If you get free time you can see the following links .. There you can find clear concept about different ways to handle click events

http://www.remwebdevelopment.com/dev/a69/Different-Ways-To-Handle-Clicks.html

http://smartcloudblog.blogspot.com/2011/09/android-onclicklisteners-vs.html

Comment: i followed your advice and i dont get the error anymore. However, nothing happens. When i click the button, it is supposed to trigger the method, and connect to my server, but it does not.

Comment: have you checked whether your startClient method trigerred? put a log in there. There is other possibilities of connection problem

Comment: i put a log.i("hello", "itworks") there, and it does get triggered. I suppose the problem is the ip and port? Perhaps it is something else when using android emulators.

Comment: if you are using private ip then both server and client have to be in the same private network... check this.. also check whether the server and client;s port is correct. finally check if your thread is connected? and whether there is any exception caught. put some logs in there too

Comment: im not using a private ip, 127.0.0.1 is the current one, i changed it to this one recently. i have the same port for both server and client, and it is 5554 which my emulator has. my thread is not connected, i have logs there and system.out.printlns as well, in my server class

Answer (score 3):

When you define the click method of a button in XML, the button itself is passed as a parameter to the method.

You have a `startClient()` method, but Android is looking for a `startClient(View v)` method. Change your method to match this signature and it will work.

Comment: i followed your advice and i dont get the error anymore. However, nothing happens. When i click the button, it is supposed to trigger the method, and connect to my server, but it does not.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to reply earlier, but I hope @StinePike 's answer worked out for you...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I still cant get the connection to work. The method is being triggered, but I get no connection from the client to the server. socket.connect(ipPort); this line does nothing at the moment

Answer (score 1):

Change `public void startClient()` to `public void startClient(View v)`.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
public void startClient() {
```

with:

```
public void startClient(View view) {
```

The methon onClick take a parameter, the View.