# Button Press Does Not Seem To Work

Tags: android, button, notifications

The following code is for setting a custom notification.  I have managed to set my variables such as the date and time picker, etc.  but my button press to get everything going does not seem to work.  I don't get the toast and the activity seems to force close.

My button in the xml...

```
            <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/button_set_notifications"
            android:text="Set Your Notifications"
            android:background="@color/green_A700"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:onClick="SetNotificationsButton"/>
```

I realize it's a lot of code but heres everything to add the notification.

```
public class GrowAssistantActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener,
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

private EditText mTitleText;
private TextView mDateText, mTimeText, mRepeatText, mRepeatNoText, mRepeatTypeText;
//private FloatingActionButton mFAB1;
//private FloatingActionButton mFAB2;
private Calendar mCalendar;
private int mYear, mMonth, mHour, mMinute, mDay;
private long mRepeatTime;
private String mTitle;
private String mTime;
private String mDate;
private String mRepeat;
private String mRepeatNo;
private String mRepeatType;
private String mActive;

// Values for orientation change
private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title_key";
private static final String KEY_TIME = "time_key";
private static final String KEY_DATE = "date_key";
private static final String KEY_REPEAT = "repeat_key";
private static final String KEY_REPEAT_NO = "repeat_no_key";
private static final String KEY_REPEAT_TYPE = "repeat_type_key";
private static final String KEY_ACTIVE = "active_key";

// Constant values in milliseconds
private static final long milMinute = 60000L;
private static final long milHour = 3600000L;
private static final long milDay = 86400000L;
private static final long milWeek = 604800000L;
private static final long milMonth = 2592000000L;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grow_assistant_activity_layout);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Grow Assistant");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // Initialize Views
    mTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reminder_title);
    mDateText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.set_date);
    mTimeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.set_time);
    mRepeatText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.set_repeat);
    mRepeatNoText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.set_repeat_no);
    mRepeatTypeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.set_repeat_type);
    //mFAB1 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.starred1);
    //mFAB2 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.starred2);

// Initialize default values
    mActive = "true";
    mRepeat = "true";
    mRepeatNo = Integer.toString(1);
    mRepeatType = "Hour";

    mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    mHour = mCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    mMinute = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    mYear = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    mDay = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DATE);

    mDate = mDay + "/" + mMonth + "/" + mYear;
    mTime = mHour + ":" + mMinute;

    // Setup Reminder Title EditText
    mTitleText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            mTitle = s.toString().trim();
            mTitleText.setError(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    });

    // Setup TextViews using reminder values
    mDateText.setText(mDate);
    mTimeText.setText(mTime);
    mRepeatNoText.setText(mRepeatNo);
    mRepeatTypeText.setText(mRepeatType);
    mRepeatText.setText("Every " + mRepeatNo + " " + mRepeatType + "(s)");

    // To save state on device rotation
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        String savedTitle = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_TITLE);
        mTitleText.setText(savedTitle);
        mTitle = savedTitle;

        String savedTime = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_TIME);
        mTimeText.setText(savedTime);
        mTime = savedTime;

        String savedDate = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_DATE);
        mDateText.setText(savedDate);
        mDate = savedDate;

        String saveRepeat = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_REPEAT);
        mRepeatText.setText(saveRepeat);
        mRepeat = saveRepeat;

        String savedRepeatNo = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_REPEAT_NO);
        mRepeatNoText.setText(savedRepeatNo);
        mRepeatNo = savedRepeatNo;

        String savedRepeatType = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_REPEAT_TYPE);
        mRepeatTypeText.setText(savedRepeatType);
        mRepeatType = savedRepeatType;

        mActive = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_ACTIVE);
    }

    /*/ Setup up active buttons
    if (mActive.equals("false")) {
        mFAB1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mFAB2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    } else if (mActive.equals("true")) {
        mFAB1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mFAB2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }/*/
}

// To save state on device rotation
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putCharSequence(KEY_TITLE, mTitleText.getText());
    outState.putCharSequence(KEY_TIME, mTimeText.getText());
    outState.putCharSequence(KEY_DATE, mDateText.getText());
    outState.putCharSequence(KEY_REPEAT, mRepeatText.getText());
    outState.putCharSequence(KEY_REPEAT_NO, mRepeatNoText.getText());
    outState.putCharSequence(KEY_REPEAT_TYPE, mRepeatTypeText.getText());
    outState.putCharSequence(KEY_ACTIVE, mActive);
}

// On clicking Time picker
public void setTime(View v){
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimePickerDialog tpd = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(
            this,
            now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
            now.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
            false
    );
    tpd.setThemeDark(false);
    tpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Timepickerdialog");
}

// On clicking Date picker
public void setDate(View v){
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
            this,
            now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    );
    dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
}

// Obtain time from time picker
@Override
public void onTimeSet(RadialPickerLayout view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    mHour = hourOfDay;
    mMinute = minute;
    if (minute < 10) {
        mTime = hourOfDay + ":" + "0" + minute;
    } else {
        mTime = hourOfDay + ":" + minute;
    }
    mTimeText.setText(mTime);
}

// Obtain date from date picker
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    monthOfYear ++;
    mDay = dayOfMonth;
    mMonth = monthOfYear;
    mYear = year;
    mDate = dayOfMonth + "/" + monthOfYear + "/" + year;
    mDateText.setText(mDate);
}

/*/ On clicking the active button
public void selectFab1(View v) {
    mFAB1 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.starred1);
    mFAB1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mFAB2 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.starred2);
    mFAB2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mActive = "true";
}/*/

/*/ On clicking the inactive button
public void selectFab2(View v) {
    mFAB2 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.starred2);
    mFAB2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mFAB1 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.starred1);
    mFAB1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mActive = "false";
}/*/

// On clicking the repeat switch
public void onSwitchRepeat(View view) {
    boolean on = ((Switch) view).isChecked();
    if (on) {
        mRepeat = "true";
        mRepeatText.setText("Every " + mRepeatNo + " " + mRepeatType + "(s)");
    } else {
        mRepeat = "false";
        mRepeatText.setText(R.string.repeat_off);
    }
}

// On clicking repeat type button
public void selectRepeatType(View v){
    final String[] items = new String[5];

    items[0] = "Every Minute";
    items[1] = "Hourly";
    items[2] = "Daily";
    items[3] = "Weekly";
    items[4] = "Monthly";

    // Create List Dialog
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Select Type");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

            mRepeatType = items[item];
            mRepeatTypeText.setText(mRepeatType);
            mRepeatText.setText("Every " + mRepeatNo + " " + mRepeatType + "(s)");
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

// On clicking repeat interval button
public void setRepeatNo(View v){
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Enter Number");

    // Create EditText box to input repeat number
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    alert.setView(input);
    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    if (input.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                        mRepeatNo = Integer.toString(1);
                        mRepeatNoText.setText(mRepeatNo);
                        mRepeatText.setText("Every " + mRepeatNo + " " + mRepeatType + "(s)");
                    }
                    else {
                        mRepeatNo = input.getText().toString().trim();
                        mRepeatNoText.setText(mRepeatNo);
                        mRepeatText.setText("Every " + mRepeatNo + " " + mRepeatType + "(s)");
                    }
                }
            });
    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // do nothing
        }
    });
    alert.show();
}

// On clicking the set notifications button
public void SetNotificationsButton(){
    ReminderDatabase rb = new ReminderDatabase(this);

    // Creating Reminder
    int ID = rb.addReminder(new Reminder(mTitle, mDate, mTime, mRepeat, mRepeatNo, mRepeatType, mActive));

    // Set up calender for creating the notification
    mCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, --mMonth);
    mCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, mYear);
    mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDay);
    mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mHour);
    mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinute);
    mCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    // Check repeat type
    if (mRepeatType.equals("Minute")) {
        mRepeatTime = Integer.parseInt(mRepeatNo) * milMinute;
    } else if (mRepeatType.equals("Hour")) {
        mRepeatTime = Integer.parseInt(mRepeatNo) * milHour;
    } else if (mRepeatType.equals("Day")) {
        mRepeatTime = Integer.parseInt(mRepeatNo) * milDay;
    } else if (mRepeatType.equals("Week")) {
        mRepeatTime = Integer.parseInt(mRepeatNo) * milWeek;
    } else if (mRepeatType.equals("Month")) {
        mRepeatTime = Integer.parseInt(mRepeatNo) * milMonth;
    }

    // Create a new notification
    if (mActive.equals("true")) {
        if (mRepeat.equals("true")) {
            new AlarmReceiver().setRepeatAlarm(getApplicationContext(), mCalendar, ID, mRepeatTime);
        } else if (mRepeat.equals("false")) {
            new AlarmReceiver().setAlarm(getApplicationContext(), mCalendar, ID);
        }
    }

    // Create toast to confirm new reminder
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    onBackPressed();
}

// On pressing the back button
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
}
```

my logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.cannamaster.growassistant.mmj, PID: 32671
                                                                                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5106)
                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20329)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5912)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5106) 
                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20329) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5912) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200) 
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component class com.cannamaster.growassistant.mmj.grow_assistant.BootReceiver does not exist in com.cannamaster.growassistant.mmj
                                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1550)
                                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
                                                                                   at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.setComponentEnabledSetting(IPackageManager.java:4116)
                                                                                   at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1967)
                                                                                   at com.cannamaster.growassistant.mmj.grow_assistant.AlarmReceiver.setRepeatAlarm(AlarmReceiver.java:120)
                                                                                   at com.cannamaster.growassistant.mmj.grow_assistant.GrowAssistantActivity.SetNotificationsButton(GrowAssistantActivity.java:341)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5106) 
                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20329) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5912) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                       at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [run method onclick crash in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339399/run-method-onclick-crash-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your method syntax as below:

```
public void SetNotificationsButton(View view){
 // Method must have View Object as parameter.
}
```

Comment: I made your suggested changes and still get a force close and no toast.  I have added my logcat to the original question.

Comment: I removed all of my code except the toast and your solution at least lets me show the toast so the force close problem must be else ware in my code.  Thank You.